# NativeScript - framework not found (IQKeyboardManager)

Tags: frameworks, nativescript, iqkeyboardmanager

When I use IQKeyboardManager in NativeScript, it works good in my project, but when I use **Xcode build/archive** release, this error appears:

> framework not found IQKeyboardManager

[image: image of error]

Has anyone had the same issue?

Comment: I don't do much iOS but I know recently cocoapods requires 1.0 (I heard that somewhere). Other than that no clue I have it in a production app published last week.

Comment: i don't know the reason, but i change other to publish apple store, use de nativescript doc tns publish ios ~it's okay.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4560

> You have to open xcode workspace file in the directory using Xcode IDE, not the xcode project file